# apache2 This site can’t be reached when using php5.6

Tags: php, apache, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

been working in ubuntu 16.04 and i have apache2 with php installed.
all is good and i can switch version from php 7.0 - 7.4 without any issues.

now i have to setup a project developed using php5.6.

installed it normally

```
sudo-apt install php5.6
```

switch php for cli using

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

was able to switch successfully. but when i change the php for apache.

```
sudo a2dismod php7.1 ; sudo a2enmod php5.6 ; sudo service apache2 restart
```

I can no longer access my localhost. it only returns an error.

```
This site can’t be reached

localhost refused to connect.
```

switching back to other php version (7.x) will fix it. but i need to use php5.6.

also no errors in /var/log/apache2/error.log

did i do some mistakes on php5.6 installation or there are some apache configs missing?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

found the cause of the error. you should make sure no other php7.x are enabled on your apache. ive been switching versions and didnt realize i left 7.4 enabled.

sudo a2dismod php7.0, sudo a2dismod php7.1, sudo a2dismod php7.2........

until i made sure that everything was disabled aside from php5.6